# Removing empty line from .xml using unix script

Tags: sed

I wanted to remove empty lines from an XML file, but after using the command `sed -e '/^$/d' file.xml  > file2.xml` it does not show the trailer record.

I opened the XML file with Notepad++ to check the record count.

Comment: What's a "trailer record"?

Comment: @glennjackman trailer would mean last, so trailer record would no doubt mean last record  Anyhow, you can google it, I just did right now, and I can see that he clearly didn't make the term up.

Comment: It's up to the asker to ask a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use translate (tr) command. Here is an example which will display your data without white space:

```
cat yourxmlfile.xml | tr -d "[:space:]"
```

Comment: Removing all whitespace will destroy the separation between a tag and its attributea